# Rails/pg group_by average between two records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a schema in which I would like to calculate the "average checkout time". i.e. Books `have_many` check_outs. A check_out will have a `type` and `time` column.

I want to find the average checkout time for each book between a respective type `in` and `out`. I'm a bit new to grouping queries. I'be been fiddling in the console for a while, but to no avail. I can do basic groupings, but not sure how to query efficiency.

I believe this is a simple question, but if is complex please advise.

My current thinking is to:

1. group each check_in and check_out by book_id
2. average check_in date
3. average check_out date
4. take the difference of check_in - check_out per book

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
CheckOut.group(:book_id).average('check_out - check_in')
```

This is equivalent to the average check_out - average check_in, which would look like this:

```
CheckOut.group(:book_id).average(:check_out) - CheckOut.group(:book_id).average(:check_in)
```

I'm not sure which query would be more efficient, but I would guess the former.

Comment: Close...problem is that each record has a type of `check_out` or `check_in`, so I need a where `check_type: :check_out`...that's really where I'm tripped.

Answer (score 0):

since check out and check in are separate records, I think you will need to fetch them separately, like the second choice above. Also, I realized that answer doesn't make sense as it's calculating the difference between two data sets. So, really you want something like this:

```
check_outs = Check.where(check_type: :check_out).group(:book_id).average(:time)
check_ins = Check.where(check_type: :check_in).group(:book_id).average(:time)
```

I think these will be hashes keyed on the book_id, so you can iterate through the list and get the values:

```
times = {}
check_ins.each_with_index do |v, i|
  times[i] = v - check_outs[i]
end
```

There is an additional issue here, which is that if a book is currently checked out, then it won't have a check_in record, and it will throw off the averages.

Comment: This looks pretty good based on my request...I'm getting this error currently: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function avg(timestamp without time zone) does not exist`...

Comment: looks like Postgres doesn't support avg on timestamp. Maybe you can cast it as an integer - instead of passing :time to average, you'd need something like this: `'cast(time) to integer'` or maybe `'EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE time'` I'm afraid I don't have postgres running here so I'm not able to test anything